# VBA - Can't save workbook due to a naming error. (Error 1004) Not sure how to fix the program

Tags: excel, vba, path, save, filenames

Function export_to_csv(ws As Worksheet, filename As String, filepath As String, fileRange As String)
Dim LastRow As Long

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

If ws.AutoFilterMode Then Cells.AutoFilter

ws.Activate
LastRow = ws.Range(Left(fileRange, 2) & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
  
ws.Range(fileRange & LastRow).AutoFilter Field:=11, Criteria1:="<50"
On Error Resume Next
Set dataRange = ws.Range(fileRange & LastRow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
On Error GoTo 0
If dataRange Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox ("No record!")
Else
    dataRange.Copy
    '--- create a temporary workbook that will be saved as a XLSX format
    Dim tempWB As Workbook
    Set tempWB = Application.Workbooks.Add(1)
    tempWB.Sheets(1).Activate
    With tempWB.Sheets(1).Range("A1")
        .PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    End With
    
    tempWB.Sheets(1).Range("A:A").NumberFormat = "Text"
    tempWB.Sheets(1).Range("f:f").NumberFormat = "0.0000"
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    tempWB.SaveAs filename:=filepath & filename, FileFormat:=51, _
                  CreateBackup:=False, Local:=True
    tempWB.Close SaveChanges:=False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    MsgBox (filename & " exported!")
End If

ws.Cells.AutoFilter
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

I have a macro that is essentially pulling a section of the records (1-50, 50-100, etc.) and saving it in it's own workbook. The date that the filepath was created (August 2022) works fine, but when I update it to the current month (May 2023), the code breaks, and I can't use the macros anymore.

I tried to change the workbooks from Active to Current since it seemed like that was the issue with it others had but it didn't make much of a difference. I think the problem might come with routing back to for the filepath and filename but i'm unsure how to pull it from another workbook when the code is in a temporary one at the moment.

Comment: What does `Debug.Print filepath & filename` return in the Immediate Window?

Comment: @BigBen where would I put that line of code? at the end?

Comment: Right before `tempWB.SaveAs filename:=filepath & filename...`

Comment: @BigBen you cannot save this workbook as the same name as another open workbook.

Answer (score 0):

There is an error of the full path and/or name of the file,
can be:

- Character which is not allowed to use

```
 < (less than)
 > greater than
 : (colon)
" (double quote)
/ (forward slash)
\ (backslash)
| (vertical bar or pipe)
? (question mark)
* (asterisk)
```

- Two backslash directly followed
- The defined name not exist in the directory